# Elastic search aggregations buckets counting email format as two different bucket key .

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field stored as "user1@user.com " .

Using aggregations json query :

```
"aggregations": {
                "email-terms": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "l_obj.email",
                        "size": 0,
                        "shard_size": 0,
                        "order": {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


I am getting response :

"buckets" : [
{
"key" : "user.com",
"doc_count" : 1
},
{
"key" : "user1",
"doc_count" : 1
}
```

instead of

```
"buckets" : [
{
"key" : "user1@user.com",
"doc_count" : 1
}
]
```

Same issue persists for string type likes : user1.user2.user.com ,I am doing terms aggregations .
Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [`"index": "not_analyzed"`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) on the `"email"` field in your mapping.

If I set up a toy index without specifying an analyzer (or to not use one), the [standard analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used, which will split on whitespace and symbols like "@". So, with this index definition:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "email": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

if I add a single doc:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "email": "user1@user.com"
}
```

and then ask for a `terms` aggregation, I get back two terms:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggregations": {
      "email-terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "email"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "email-terms": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "user.com",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "user1",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But if I rebuild the index with `"index": "not_analyzed"` in that field, and again index the same document:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "email": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "email": "user1@user.com"
}
```

and run the same terms aggregation, I only get back a single term for that email address:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggregations": {
      "email-terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "email"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "email-terms": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "user1@user.com",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used, altogether:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a73a28bf7450b637138b02a371fb15cabf344ab6

Comment: Thanks Sloan , that was helpful ,For us configuring analyzers using index template worked . http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use index template to predefined field types ,http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html
 ,ex :

Use rest client or elastic search sense

```
PUT/POST http://escluster:port/_template

{
  "testtemplate": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "test1": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "email": {
            "fielddata": {
              "format": "doc_values"
            },
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
          }...
```